# DNS A record on Domain host differs from DNS A record on Web host

Tags: dns, php, domain, domain-name

My domain host has one A @ record. The IP address value listed is completely different from the A @ record listed for my web host. I did not change any of them.

I hadn't visited the site in years nor made changes to the back end domain or web host account; I had set the index page to the site to show a message to come back soon because the site was old and was going to be updated but I never got around to it.

It now says "Website Unavailable: The website you are trying to reach is unavailable." with a registered mark for "RunCloud(r) - Cool Code Sdn. Bhd." in the corner.

The files are still there (even the original index page), the web host is paid up, the domain is paid in full.

Google-fu says RunCloud is a PHP Cloud Server Management Panel. I did not set that up.

What's going on? Is the cause the fact that the A records don't match between the domain and web host? Was my website hacked? Is it an underlying PHP error from my webhost?

Comment: Do you know *which* of the two addresses in your A records is the correct one? (The web host should tell you what their server's IP address is.) Have you checked which **nameservers** are currently configured for the domain at your registrar – do they point at your "domain host" or at your "web host"? Only the configured nameservers will be queried for the A record in the first place; all others don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier and we could answer more authoratively if you provided the IP addresses and hostname in question.

It sounds like your web host has reconfigured their network / changed the IP address the web server binds to and neglected to inform you to update the A records at your provider.

It is unlikely from what you have written that your website was hacked, and it is unlikely that it is a PHP error from the webhost, although I can conceive of ways that either of these options could be true.

Regardless, you should be reaching out to your webhost in the first instance.

Answer (score 0):

According to my domain host support, no one accessed the account, yet someone changed the A @ record IP to point to a fraud site located in China. The web host A record IP was the correct one.

An hour of talking to/confirming things with both host and domain support chat (at the same time!) and I corrected the A @ record on the domain to point to the proper IP for the web host. Another 3 hours of waiting for minimal DNS propagation and things are working again.